# remove the keys which has blank values

Tags: python, dictionary

how to remove keys in a dict which do not have any value. I have a dict as :

```
d = {'CB': '', 'CA': [-7.5269999504089355, -2.2330000400543213, 6.748000144958496], 'C': [-8.081000328063965, -3.619999885559082, 6.406000137329102], 'N': [-6.626999855041504, -2.318000078201294, 7.9029998779296875], 'H':''}
```

I want to remove keys which values are blank. I need output as :

```
d = {'CA': [-7.5269999504089355, -2.2330000400543213, 6.748000144958496], 'C': [-8.081000328063965, -3.619999885559082, 6.406000137329102], 'N': [-6.626999855041504, -2.318000078201294, 7.9029998779296875]}
```

how to do this?

Comment: Why is "in one line" a requirement? Which part are you having difficulty with? Identifying the "blank" values? Removing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in d.items() if v != ''}
{'N': [-6.626999855041504, -2.318000078201294, 7.9029998779296875], 'CA': [-7.5269999504089355, -2.2330000400543213, 6.748000144958496], 'C': [-8.081000328063965, -3.619999885559082, 6.406000137329102]}
```

If by empty you meant any falsy value then use just `if v`.

---

If you want to modify the original dict itself(this will affect all the references to the dict object):

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if not v: del d[k]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>> {key:value for key, value in d.items() if value}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this in one-line:

```
for k in [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if not v]: del d[k]
```

This is ugly. It makes a list of all of the keys in `d` that have a "blank" value and then iterates over this list removing the keys from `d` (to avoid  the unsafe removal of items from dictionary during iteration).

I'd suggest that three lines would be more readable:

```
blanks = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if not v]
for k in blanks:
    del d[k]
```

If making a fresh `dict` is acceptable, use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
d2 = {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if not v}
```